# КАК сдедлать отправку в определнное время aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(state=user_reg.send)
async def sending(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    while True:
        us_tm = get_time(chat_id)
        f = datetime.now()
        now_secs = f.second
        now_hours = f.hour
        now_mins = f.minute
        us_secs = int(us_tm[6:8])
        us_mins = int(us_tm[3:5])
        us_hours = int(us_tm[0:2])
        if now_secs == us_secs:
            if now_hours == us_hours:
                if now_mins == us_mins:
                    currency = get_currency(chat_id)
                    global url
                    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={currency}+rub'
                    global headers
                    headers = {
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}
                    currency_1 = get_currency_price()
                    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"<b>Курс валюты на данный момент:</b>\n"
                                                            f"{currency_1} рублей", parse_mode='html')

th = Thread(target=sending).start()






@dp.message_handler(state=user_reg.reg_time)
async def reg_time(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    await state.finish()
    add_time(message)
    status = add_time(message)
    us_tm = get_time(chat_id)
    if status == False:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, "Неверное время!")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Успешно добавлено время отправки:\n"
                                        f"<b>{us_tm}</b>", parse_mode='html')
        await user_reg.send.set()
```

Это бот для проверки курса валют, которую он берет из БД и парсит из гугла курс, затем нужно отправить в запланированное пользователем время. Подскажите, как это сделать корректней? Мои основные проблемы:

1. Как сделать проверку время постоянной в фоновом режиме?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы для получения chat_id боту не пришлось ничего присылать
3. И как сделать так, чтобы ботом можно было спокойно пользоваться, пока курс ожидает своей отправки в нужное время?

Comment: Нужен будет бесконечный цикл, который будет постоянно проверять время, и когда условие по времени будет True, тогда юзеру приходит сообщение. Можно написать такую функцию и запустить её асинхронно при запуске бота, но если хочешь прям полную параллельность. Тогда запустить в другом процессе, например, с помощью модуля concurrent.futures. Что-бы получить chat_id, нужно что-бы юзер хоть когда твой бот взаимодействовал с ним. Элементарно нажал кнопку /start, тогда ты можешь сохранить его chat_id допустим в бд и отсылать ему сообщения, пока он тебя не заблочит

Comment: На третий вопрос ответ в первом

Answer (score 0):

Ниже прикреплю код в качестве примера того, как это можно реализовать.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime, time
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types


API_TOKEN = 'your_token_here'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Я бот, который отправляет сообщения в определенное время.")


async def scheduled(wait_for):
    while True:
        now = datetime.now().time()
        # Устанавливаем желаемое время отправки сообщения
        send_time = time(hour=8, minute=0, second=0)

        if now > send_time:
            tomorrow = datetime.combine(datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1), send_time)
            wait_for = (tomorrow - datetime.now()).total_seconds()

        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)

        # Отправляем сообщение в определенное время
        await bot.send_message(chat_id='chat_id_here', text='Это сообщение отправлено в определенное время!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(scheduled(0))  # Здесь можно указать первоначальную задержку (в секундах)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(dp.start_polling())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.close()
```